# How do I use Click Element function to select the "li" id with robot framework?

Tags: selenium, xpath, robotframework

I am unable to select any of the ul id/li class items. I tried to use the 
    **"click element    xpath=class('submenu')/li[text()='Overall Schedule']"** 
But it return

> "InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate
>   an element with the xpath expression
>   class('submenu')/li[text()='Single Day Schedule'] because of the
>   following error: SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on
>   'Document': The string 'class('submenu')/li[text()='Single Day
>   Schedule']' is not a valid XPath expression."

Elements

```
<li class="scheduler" style="">
              <a href="#" title="Schedule"><span>Schedule</span></a>

              <ul class="submenu">

                  <li id="sche" style="">
                  <a href="schedule.html">Single Day Schedule</a>
                  </li>

                  <li id="nsch" style="">
                  <a href="net-schedule.html">Overall Schedule</a>
                  </li>

              </ul>
          </li>
```

Can anyone help me to use?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you got a HTML example? That would really help!

Comment: Thanks for reminding, I add in the description.

Comment: The error is self-explanatory - the passed string is not an xpath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
class('submenu')/li[text()='Overall Schedule']
```

try

```
//ul[@class='submenu']/li[.='Overall Schedule']
```

Answer (score 0):

Always the **xpath** should start with 2 fwd slashes

(For **relative xpath** writing).

you can try the below xpath

```
Xpath = //li[@id='sche']
```

Comment: *"Always the xpath should start with 2 fwd slashes"*... Actually, no. It can start with, for example,  `./`

Comment: @Andersson in general you're right, xpath expression can start a number of ways; yet the `//` prefix is most commonly used - "get to the starting element wherever it's in the DOM". And in fact, that's how RF autosenses what is the passed locator type - if the user hasn't prefixed it with "xpath=" but it starts with "//", it threats it as such; and also, in RF a relative locator - "./" - can't be used - you cannot pass an element as context for relativeness. I agree OPs statement was too general and imposing limits that don't exist, yet in RF it's 98% correct.